# I would like to change a worksheets name to the filename during a loop as I open its workbook VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently using this code to open all .xls files in a folder

```
Sub OpenFiles()

    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    MyFolder = InputBox("Please enter the folder for files")
    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xls")
    Do While MyFile <> ""
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile
        ****Sheet1.Name = "MyFile"****
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

I am trying to change the worksheet name to the file name as it loops though

Every worksheet I am opening will be called "Parts List"

I am trying to use the asterisk portion to do this but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will rename the Worksheets("Parts List") in the newly opened workbook to MyFile.

```
Sub OpenFiles()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    MyFolder = InputBox("Please enter the folder for files")
    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xls")
    Do While MyFile <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile)

        wb.Worksheets("Parts List").Name = MyFile

        MyFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line to:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "MyFile"
```